# How to check string on date in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, time

How to check string on date in laravel?

I want to handle the situation if string doesn't date for example like "it's some not date string".

I try it code, but it doesn't work I have next error:

```
InvalidArgumentException  : A two digit month could not be found
Data missing
```

My code:

```
    if (Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $rowMatrix[4]) !== false) {
//
}
```

Comment: what is `$rowMatrix` provide its value

Comment: Is the string is always in this format `m-d-Y` if it's a date ?

Comment: @GaneshGhalame  it's just string that can contain date. I need check it on date.

Comment: @Maraboc No, but it doesn't metter in this case. Some times $rowMatrix[4] can contain just string(name of column, for example) and I need validate it

Comment: I mean if it's a date you have one format ?

Comment: @Maraboc okay, it can contain only one format. So in this way i need check this sting is date or another string, name of colun(in my case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` for this purpose :

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $rowMatrix[4]);
$errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
if (!empty($errors['warning_count'])) {
    // Not a date
}
```

Or you can check it like this :

```
if (date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($rowMatrix[4])) == $rowMatrix[4]){
    // it's a date
}
```

Comment: If do it in native PHP it's good solve, thank you. Just I think that exist Laravel solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [try/catch block](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

```
try {
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $rowMatrix[4])
} catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    $date = 'Not a date';
}
```

But a much better way is to use Laravel validation [`date_format`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date-format) rule to make sure the string is a date:

```
'some_date_field' => 'date_format:"m-d-Y"',
```

Comment: if(['sdsdsd' => 'date_format:"m-d-Y"']){
echo "a";
}else{
    echo "b";
}

Why it doesn't work? I expect "b", but I have "a"

Comment: @befreeforlife you're doing it wrong. You might want to learn about how does [Laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) work first.

Comment: yea.. So, in this case more fit native PHP solution - like  try/catch block

Comment: @befreeforlife as I said, it's always better to use validation for that when possible. If it's not possible for some reason, use the `try/catch` block to catch the exception.